# Just wondering if this is poor JS coding practice

Tags: javascript, null

I have 2 separate functionalities on one page of my site, both of which call the same Ajax function. The 2 functionalities need to be distinguishable. My solution was to pass a string (called **string** here) in one of the functions, such as in the following simplified example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction(string) {
    if (string === 'String') {
        alert('You have clicked Button2');
    } else {
        alert('You have clicked Button1');
    }    
}
</script>

<button type="button" id="Button1" onclick="AjaxFunction()">Click1</button>
<button type="button" id="Button2" onclick="AjaxFunction('String')">Click2</button>
```

This seems perfectly fine to me. The only issue is that **string** is null when Button1 is clicked. I imagine there is no problem with this since the if...else takes care of any ambiguity of what to do with **string**. I have tested with my actual Ajax function and everything works OK, but since I am still somewhat new to coding I always imagine that stupid mistakes I am not aware of will destroy the site. Sorry for the trivial question but am I missing any performance issues, bugs, etc. with this approach? Thank you for any help!

Comment: You're asking for opinions, so I'll point out that inline JavaScript code and old-school "onfoo" event handler code are considered poor coding practice.

Comment: only issue I see is using inline events. Most developers would use a data attribute or class on the element and have the function check.

Comment: @epascarello well if it's really trying to distinguish one button from another, it'd be better to pass `this` so that the function gets the actual DOM node involved. (In my opinion.)

Comment: Thanks...you're absolutely correct. The actual JS function is in external file.

Comment: If they are doing different things why do they need to call the same function?

Comment: Currently I'm using document.getElementById('buttonID').click() to click other buttons after Ajax function call has run its course....used "this" for other functions...worked great.

Comment: @Danny, My bad for the poor wording of my comment....they are separate elements on the page that have different IDs and html.....but they both send mail via Ajax when all is said and done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an empty string into the first button call. So:

```
onclick="AjaxFunction('')"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...would an empty string have an advantage over no string at all (i.e., AjaxFunction() )?

Comment: If the function is expecting a parameter, an error will be thrown if none is passed.